# Gray and RGB both in one GIF file

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is there any Matlab method that merge gray scale images with RGB images without making the gray scale image look like it's all blur

Comment: You've just used `im2=rgb2gray(im1);` and haven't changed it. So why should `im2` be colored?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the role of `im3`?

Comment: @Kamtal  this is what i need to know, im2 should not be colored, but when i run the code, Oops! it's colored.

Comment: im3 is the GIF result which is made up from im1 and im2

Comment: I ran the code and `im2` is gray. Do you want the saved `homework` to be gray?

Comment: in this line 'im3(ys_moves1,xs_moves)=im2(ys_moves1,xs_moves);' should not im3 be gray-scaled at the given coordinates ?! (the result should appear in homework.gif)

Comment: No, I can give you an example in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose,

```
a = randi(255,[2 2 3])

a(:,:,1) =
245   205
124    37
a(:,:,2) =
108   203
234   245
a(:,:,3) =
168   217
10   239
```

You can imagine `a` as an `rgb` image, now,

```
a(1,2) = 10 % its like  'im3(ys_moves1,xs_moves)=im2(ys_moves1,xs_moves);'
```

Then you have

```
a(:,:,1) =
245   10
124    37
a(:,:,2) =
108   203
234   245
a(:,:,3) =
168   217
10   239
```

As you can see `a` is still an `rgb` image and you have only changed its `red` parameter.

Comment: thanks,got it , so then what should replace 'im3(ys_moves1,xs_moves)=im2(ys_moves1,xs_moves);'

Comment: @Djhseen, you want `im3` to be gray? or both gray and rgb??

Comment: @Djhseen, as far as I know that is not possible, because grays are 2D and RGBs are 3D. may I ask what is your homework? may be I could help.

Comment: the homework is to code somthing that create this GIF  [link](http://i.imgur.com/xLYbdxE.gif)

Comment: @Djhseen, That's interesting. I'm not good with image processing, let see what can I do.

Comment: @Djhseen, I think you should ask a new question, may be other ppl can help.

Comment: i think i found the solution. thank you, i used the idea you explained in your example.